# Angular 5 Call Function On Input() Bind

Tags: angular, input, data-binding, angular5

Sorry if the title is confusing, not sure how to word it. I am trying to call a function to get data and pass it to a child component.

**parent.component.ts**:

```
getData(arg: string[]) {
    let data: any[];

    // Do stuff here to get data

    return data;
}
```

**parent.component.html**:

```
<app-child [myData]="getData(['test'])"></app-child>
```

**child.component.ts**

```
export class ChildComponent {

    @Input() myData: any[];

    // Stuff here
}
```

**child.component.html**

```
<h3>{{ myData[0].test }}</h3>
```

However, when I run the application, I get an error saying that it `Cannot read property '0' of undefined`. What am I doing wrong? I don't want to create a variable to bind to `[myData]` because I would then have a lot of them. I will be using this function in other places as well.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Is there any http request happening when getData() is called? Or subscription to any other service?

Comment: There is not. I found it weird too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function parameter should not be with [],change it as

```
<app-child [myData]="getData('test')"></app-child>
```

and use safe navigation operator on the child to make sure the data is not emptyu

```
<h3>{{ myData[0]?.test }}</h3>
```

Comment: I don't understand. Why remove `[]`? The function takes an array. I still get the same error when I remove it.

Comment: if function takes an array you just need to use the array variable

Comment: I ended up using the implicit `arguments` variable. Not sure why it didn't work the other way. Thanks!